# Get public shared link for a file stored in a private SVN repository

Tags: svn, public, sharing

I want to share a file via a public URL - this file is stored in a SVN repository.

Is it possible to get such link?

Comment: is your question answered in the meanwhile? If yes, it would be nice to share it or to accept my answer.

Comment: @hkais Not yet an answer. I'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

If your repo is accessible from "outside" (whatever private means in your eyes) you can go on commandline and type:

```
svn info <yourFile>
```

this will show you the full link to the file.

On Windows you have probably tortoiseSVN. Here you just go with rightclick on the file, now properties and go to the tab subversion. Here is the link to the file.

mod_dav_svn has the capability to provide fine graned access to the svn.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html

and here a example

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn-acl-conf
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repositories"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
   Require valid-user
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

now you only need to create a /etc/svn-auth-users which can be done with htpasswd command

and the /etc/svn-acl-conf contains the list of access controls

```
[reponame:repopath]
user = access
```

e.g.

```
[groups]
staff = john, jane

[framework:/]
john =  r
@staff = rw
```

john and jane have to be in the svn-auth-users file!

Comment: My "private" means only the registered ones can access the file via entering their user name and password. 

The public shared link allows the file to be downloaded without asking for username/password.

Comment: depends on you SVN installation.
If you have a authentication/authorization around SVN, which is able to provide access to the SVN_DAV module in apache depending on your needs, yes. If not, the default setup you typically find in the net will not allow it.

Comment: Would be lovely to tell more in detail on how to make it public via SVN_DAV. Thank you!